# snowflake : cannot recursively parse xml

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having this xml

```
<product product-id="P001">
  <images>
    <image-group view-type="vt01">
      <image path="IP001">
        <title xml:lang="default"></title>
      </image>
      <image path="IP002">
        <title xml:lang="JP"></title>
      </image>
      <image path="IP003">
        <title xml:lang="KOR"></title>
      </image>
      <image path="IP004">
        <title xml:lang="ENG"></title>
      </image>
      <image path="IP005">
        <title xml:lang="RUS"></title>
      </image>
      <image path="IP006">
        <title xml:lang="FRA"></title>
      </image>
    </image-group>
  </images>
</product>
```

I need to get all the individual **image** details for every **image-group** in a list

```
image group : vt01
  image path : IP001 
  image lang : default

  image path : IP002 
  image lang : JP

  image path : IP003 
  image lang : KOR

  image path : IP004 
  image lang : ENG

  image path : IP005 
  image lang : RUS

  image path : IP006
  image lang : FRA
```

I am now getting ONLY the FIRST level **image-group**  detail and the FIRST level **image** detail.

```
image group : vt01
  image path : IP001      
  image lang : default
```

I loaded XML to SNOWFLAKE using "copyinto" 
using this code :

```
WITH SRC AS (SELECT PARSE_XML(CAT_XML) as XML FROM "SAMPLE"."XML_02")
select
t.value:"@view-type" as VIEW_TYPE,
xmlget(t.value,'image'):"@path" as IMAGE_PATH,
xmlget(xmlget(t.value,'image'), 'title'):"@xml:lang" as TITLE_LANG
from SRC s,
table(flatten(input => to_array(xmlget(s.XML,'images'):"$"),recursive=> FALSE)) t
```

Can some one help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Parsing hierarchical XML can be like untying a Gordian Knot. You can nest get, xmlget, lateral, and flatten clauses, but that becomes unreadable and hard to maintain. My recommended approach is to take it step by step using a CTE.

You can test the following CTE. It assumes your XML is in a table named 'SRC' in a column named 'XML' defined as type variant. From there you can modify as needed to work with your copy statement.

```
with 
IMAGES("VALUE") as
(
    select "VALUE" from SRC, lateral flatten(SRC.XML:"$") IMAGES where "KEY" = '$'
),
IMAGE_ARRAY(IMAGE) as
(
    select I."VALUE" from IMAGES, lateral flatten(IMAGES."VALUE") I where "KEY" = '$'
),
IMAGE(IMAGE_XML) as
(
    select "VALUE" from IMAGE_ARRAY, lateral flatten(input => to_array(IMAGE)) IMG
)    
select get(IMAGE_XML, '@path')::string as PATH,
       get(get(IMAGE_XML, '$'), '@xml:lang')::string  as LANG
from   IMAGE
;
```

Comment: seems to be a good option, but I think I may need to do some joins to get recursive level data